# Should yum.repos.d be updated?

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux, and many people say that you should update your repository.

I don't understand what they are talking about. 
Is it like updating OS of smart phone? 
What does it mean update repository? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mr. Walmart, there is not any easy explanation in Google

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question so the title is asking the same thing as the body?

Comment: @G-Man, ok done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unlike* windows , most linux software is installed by a package manager (which you access through a front end). "Updating your repository" means getting a fresh list of packages for your package manager. *Unlike* your phone app store, desktop applications rely on a fairly complex relationship between multiple packages so it would have information like "Package A relies on version 2.0 or more of libanana" as well, which need to be kept up to date.

*However* typically yum and dnf (the newer package manager on red hat distros) pull in updated repositories whenever you install or update packages, so you should not need to do it manually. Contrast this with apt - where you have separate commands to update your repositories, (apt-get update) and upgrade software (apt-get upgrade). So no, you shouldn't typically need to run a command to do this and chances are there's no benefit from it at all on RH based distros. On ubuntu, yeah, you should do it *periodically*, though I tend to do it before any install or upgrade command.

A smartphone update is closer to a update to a new release - on fedora, this was a command called [fedup](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp) (now rolled into dnf) and on ubuntu its "do-release-upgrade".

Answer (score 0):

yum stands for yellow dog updater modified. It is used for installing programs and managing packages.
In Linux distributions a repositry refers to a server that stores software for that particulat Linux distribution. One can access this repository and install any particular repository into one own computer. "yum.repos.d" is a directry into which repositories are installed. pdate command is used to update the local repository with security paatches. http://www.slashroot.in/yum-repository-and-package-management-complete-tutorial

Comment: Update command is used to update the local repository with software modified with latest security paatches. "update downloads the package lists from the repositories and "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies. It will do this for all repositories and PPAs".